# How can I retrieve data from frontendmasters API endpoint using Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I want to retrieve all the URL's from [this](https://api.frontendmasters.com/v1/kabuki/courses/react) endpoint. The video urls are in 'lessondata' in the property 'sourcebase'.
To get to the video I have to add '?r=720&f=webm' to the 'sourcebase' url.

I have tried this strategy so far-

```
let request = require("request");

let url = "https://api.frontendmasters.com/v1/kabuki/courses/react";

request(url, function(err, response, body) {

if (err) {
    console.log("error:", error);
 } else {
    let weather = JSON.parse(body);
    let datas = weather.lessonData;

for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
  console.log(datas[i].sourceBase);
   }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Node.js version(>7.5) you can use `Object.values()` to get the values

```
let request = require("request");

let url = "https://api.frontendmasters.com/v1/kabuki/courses/react";

request(url, function(err, response, body) {

    if (err) {
        console.log("error:", error);
    } else {
        let weather = JSON.parse(body);
        let datas = weather.lessonData;
        const data = Object.values(datas).reduce((result, element) => {
            if(element.sourceBase) result.push(`${element.sourceBase}?r=720&f=webm`);
            return result;
        }, []);
    }
});
```

if you are running on old node version(<7.5) you need to use `Object.keys()` and change above logic to some entend. Please do research before asking question here as It's very simple operation

Comment: Thanks. I get those URL's in my terminal. When I make http request by using those URL's in my browser The Url has been redirected. For example https://api.frontendmasters.com/v1/kabuki/video/2785ohj0a8?r=720&f=webm  this URL is redirected to other url. I want to get that url in my cmd . How can I do that?

Comment: unable to understand your concern